# iOS Swift Draw line with a brush effect

Tags: ios, swift, drawing, core-graphics, cgcontext

I'm trying to create an app that allows to draw a line on the screen with the finger. Currently a simple blue line is drawn.
I would like to have a brush effect.

I tried CGContextDrawImage(), it doesn't work because the line is not continuous and moving the finger quickly the line turns into many distinct points.

I searched online and the only solution found is to draw the line using an image pattern but i could not use core graphics.
There is a simple way to replace the color with a pattern image?

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextBeginPath(context)

    for line in lines {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, (line.start?.x)!, (line.start?.y)!)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, (line.end?.x)!, (line.end?.y)!)
    }

    CGContextSetLineCap(context, CGLineCap.Round)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 50)
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 129/255, 196/255, 0.4)
    CGContextStrokePath(context)
}

func drawLine(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let currentPoint = gesture.locationInView(self)

    if gesture.state == .Began{
        lastPoint = currentPoint
    } else if gesture.state == .Changed {
        lines.append(Line(start: lastPoint, end: currentPoint))
        lastPoint = currentPoint
    }
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Comment: See if CGPattern is what you're looking for: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_patterns/dq_patterns.html. I'm not sure it'll be as easy as you're hoping; you may have to do all the drawing by hand in a CGBitmapContext.